# Google BigQuery - 403 - “This service is not available from your country”

Tags: google-bigquery, http-status-code-403, google-api-java-client, country

We moved our application to an other Digital Ocean Server and it stopped working with BigQuery.

403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "This service is not available from your country",
    "reason" : "countryBlocked"
  } ],
  "message" : "This service is not available from your country"
}

The server is in the Amsterdam 3 Zone. The Big Query API works on the old Digital Ocean Server (Amsterdam 1). How can we get it working in the Amsterdam 3 Zone?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a vendor support question and not a programming question as defined in the [help]. It should be addressed directly to the vendor through their support site and not here.

Comment: Do you know what IP address your request was coming from?

Comment: vendor officially offers support only on stackoverflow, which is strange, but ...

Comment: Yes, its a IPv4 address. Not sure if i am allowed to post it here

Comment: I filled a bug-report here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=197. The IP is 178.62.206.191

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an incorrect mapping of IP address by Bigquery. The support helped us by correcting the mapping of Amsterdam3-zone IP's. Now we can access the Bigqeury API from DigitalOcean's Amsterdam3-zone.